# how to make an image headerline using css

Tags: php, html

Hello everyBody
I've created a slideShow (with left and right arrows) , displaying images in three set, images are aligned horizontally, and every image is contained in a li element with a link (headline) as follows:

```
 <li><image src="image_n.jpg"></image><a href="www.google.com">Google search engine</a></li>
```

ok my question is , how can I put the headerline ("a" tag) so it covers the bottom of the image using css.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `display: block` and either a negative top margin or `position: relative` and a negative `top`.

```
li a /* or a unique identifier if it's just this instance */
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1.1 em;
}
```

or

```
li a
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -1.1em;
}
```

I'm using `em` as a unit because 1em is equal to the font size. This means that `margin-top: -1.1em` will be (approximately) a little bit more than the height of one line of text.

Comment: but My li elements are all inline , so they appear in one line, if I add (display:block) to the li a element, it turns all the li elements display:block;

Comment: Ah. Could they be changed to `float: left` instead of `display: inline`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an image tag, I would suggest using the `background-image` CSS property on the list. That way, the text will just flow over the image naturally.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know if it will be accepted but The client I am working for. :)

Comment: If you do it write the client will never know. If he throws a fit just tell him its more standards and 508 compliant. At that point they usually shake their head and walk away.

Comment: @OldCode , I work for some clients that don't shake their head without throwing questions like arrows... :)

Comment: @Simo TAQI: then its time to work on that silver tongue my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two options:
**Wrap the Image tag with the anchor tag like so:**

```
<li><a href="www.google.com"><image src="image_n.jpg"></image><psan class="caption">Google search engine</span></a></li>
```

**Remove the image tag and define the image in the background:**

```
<li><image src=""></image><a href="www.google.com" style="display:block; height:Xpx; width:Ypx; background:url(image_n.jpg);">Google search engine</a></li>
```

I prefer the latter of the two.

Comment: Thank you , I will try both of them :-)

Comment: @OldCode , I've tried all ways, but in vain...thank you anyhow.